# Java If Else statement, i have no idea what i am doing

Tags: java, if-statement

I am building a Carpark garage

I want to expand something in my code. , original it looks like this:

```
   private int exitSpeed = 10; // number of cars that can leave per minute

       // Let cars leave.

        for (int i = 0; i < exitSpeed; i++) {
            // Bye!
            if (exitCarQueue.peek() != null)
                exitCarQueue.removeCar();
            if ((car = specialExitCarQueue.peek()) != null)
                if (car instanceof ParkPassCar)
                    paymentMachine.pay(car);
            specialExitCarQueue.removeCar();
        }
```

I did something familiar with adding cars at certain hours, but i want to let move cars leave at certain hours aswell. but it aint working.

**Adding cars at certain hours:**

```
 private int weekDayArrivals= 30; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    private int weekendArrivals = 60; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    private int Concert = 300; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    private int atNight = 1; // average number of arriving cars per hour
    private int shoppingNight = 100;

       int averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = 0;
    if(hour >= 19 && hour<20 && day >=4 && day <= 6) {

        averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = Concert;

    }

    else if(day >= 5 && day <= 6 )
    {

        averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = weekendArrivals;

    }

    else if(hour >= 23 && hour<7)
    {

        averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = atNight;

    }

    else if(hour >= 18 && hour<20 && day == 3 )
    {

        averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = shoppingNight;

    }

    else{

        averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = weekDayArrivals;
    }
```

But adding if and else statements at the exit lines of code does not work.
I hope i provided enough code so you guys can maybe help me out.

thanks in advance

Comment: "it aint working" - cool, can you give us actual error messages? Warnings? Symptoms?  

Why are you checking if the hour is greater than or equal to 19, and less than 20? How about just `hour == 20` ? You're doing this weird logic all over the place. Do you really think that `hour >= 23` AND `hour < 7` can both ever be true?? 

Also, you're constantly reassigning the average... is this your intention?

Comment: Day 6 is Sunday (and probably 0 is Monday) - are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want OR clauses not AND as: hour >= 23 && hour<7 is impossible. A variable cannot be greater then 23 and lower than 7 at the same time. So you should recheck this.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your statements doesn't make any sense, like @DennisIch point out,
the follow if will never be true!

```
if(hour >= 23 && hour<7)
{
    averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = atNight;
}
```

I think you mean this:

```
if(hour >= 23 || hour < 7) //this will get the follow hours => 23 0 1 2 3 4 6 
{
    averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = atNight;
}
```

And some of your if's can be reduced, like this one:

```
if(hour >= 19 && hour<20 && day >=4 && day <= 6) {
    averageNumberOfCarsPerHour = Concert;
}
```

The first part of your statement, is equal to `hour == 19` , because the only number that satisfy this condition `hour >= 19 && hour<20` is 19!